# How can I clone files from OS X to a FAT32 formatted USB pen drive?

Tags: linux, macos, nas, rsync

I have my music library on my Synology NAS which is an ext4 file system.  I copy those files to a V-FAT formatted USB thumb drive ($usbdir), and then use the thumb drive in my car.

The problem is the --delete switch does not work.  If I delete a directory on my NAS, it is not deleted on the thumb drive, even though I am using the --delete modifier.  I've tried variations of the command shown below.  To complicate matters I'm running the rsync command from my iMac running OS X 10.11.

Is it possible to clone a ext4 directory to an FAT thumb drive, and have the --delete modifier work?

```
rsync -va --stats --delete --modify-window=1 "$stagedir/" "$usbdir"

rsync -uvrh --delete --modify-window=2 --stats --delete "$stagedir/" "$usbdir"
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that Carbon Copy Cloner uses rsync, I used CCC to copy my music files to the MS-DOS thumb drive, and it deleted files and directories on the destination, which were not on the source.  So, I ran CCC again, and used the ps command to determine what incantation CCC used, which is posted below.  From this command I should be able to derive an rsync command of my own which does the job.  Or just use CCC!

/Applications/Carbon Copy Cloner.app/Contents/MacOS/rsync -X -p --fileflags --force-change -l --max-size=4g --modify-window=1 -N -rtx --numeric-ids --sender-uid=502 --receiver-uid=0 --from0 --filter=._/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/com.bombich.ccc_filter.BYm1MU --delete-during --protect-args /Volumes/Media Library/Music Library Bernie/ /Volumes/CORSAIR